# Cartalyst/Sentinel Laravel 5.4 - Check a database field before Logging user in

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I am using Sentinel by Cartalyst in my Laravel 5.4 project. However I am tying to check the value of a database field of the 'users' table after the user provides his/her credentials for logging in.

```
if(Sentinel::authenticate($credentials, $rememberMe)) {

     $slug = Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug;
     if($slug == 'A') {
         Session::flash('welcome_message' , 'A');
         return response()->json(['redirect' => '/A/dashboard']);
     } elseif($slug == 'B') {
         Session::flash('welcome_message' , 'B');
         return response()->json(['redirect' => '/B/dashboard']);
    }
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Wrong credentials entered'], 500);
}


// if(Sentinel::getUser()->status == 'Active') -- if this is true we log in
```

The problem I cant find a way to implement this..though it checks the field but if it returns false then also the user gets logged in

Comment: Is `Sentinel::authenticate()` returns true?

Comment: @PankitGami  Sentinel::authenticate() will return true only if the user provides the correct login credentials but i want to check the 'active' field before that. if the field if not active then even after authenticate() returning true the user doesnt log in

Comment: So you want to check both. If user provide correct credential and his status must be active then only you want him to login?

Comment: You have to use checkpoint feature of sentinel.   Use this package it's provide complete implementation of sentinel with well hand code. 

https://github.com/SRLabs/Centaur

Comment: @PankitGami yes..

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty Check the answer

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
if($user = Sentinel::authenticate($credentials, $rememberMe) && $user->status == 'Active') {

     $slug = Sentinel::getUser()->roles()->first()->slug;
     if($slug == 'A') {
         Session::flash('welcome_message' , 'A');
         return response()->json(['redirect' => '/A/dashboard']);
     } elseif($slug == 'B') {
         Session::flash('welcome_message' , 'B');
         return response()->json(['redirect' => '/B/dashboard']);
    }
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Wrong credentials entered'], 500);
}
```